# VueJS - Vue is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-resource

I have challenged myself to write an app that fetches data from API and displays it in various components. I am pretty new to VueJS. I use VueResource for hitting the API and VueX for state management.
I have setup my store, I have added actions, mutation and getters, etc. and as soon as I add `created` lifecycle method in my component I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
    at Store.eval (eval at <anonymous> (build.js:1017), <anonymous>:11:3)
    at Array.wrappedActionHandler (eval at <anonymous> (build.js:1338), <anonymous>:711:23)
    at Store.dispatch (eval at <anonymous> (build.js:1338), <anonymous>:433:15)
    ...
```

My code looks like the following:

## main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import store from './store/store'

Vue.use(VueResource);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

## store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import actions from './actions'
import mutations from './mutations'
import getters from './getters'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    products: []
  },
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
})

export default store
```

## App.vue

```
<template>
   ...
</template>

<script>
    import { FETCH_MEALS } from './store/types';

    export default {
      //load meals on page load
      created() {
        this.$store.dispatch(FETCH_MEALS)
      },
      computed: {
        meals() {
          return this.$store.getters.meals
        },
        salads() {
          return this.$store.getters.salads
        },
        lunches() {
          return this.$store.getters.lunches
        },
        starters() {
          return this.$store.getters.starters
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

And I got stuck and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Do you have any ideas?

## UPDATE

I use a typical boilerplate generated by vue-cli and build main.js using Webpack.

## actions.js

```
import { API_ROOT } from '../config'
import * as types from './types';

export default {
  [types.FETCH_MEALS]: ({commit}) => {
    Vue.http.get(API_ROOT + '/meals.json')
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(meals => {
      commit(types.SET_MEALS, meals)
    })
  }
};
```

## mutations.js

```
import * as types from './types';

export default {
    [types.MUTATE_UPDATE_VALUE]: (state, payload) => {
        state.value = payload;
    }
};
```

## getters.js

```
import * as types from './types';

export default {
    [types.VALUE]: state => {
        return state.value;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're building your `main.js`? You can't just execute `main.js` directly from the browser. It needs to be transpiled down with `babel` and `vue-loader`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've updated my question. I use Webpack to build main.js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My guess is that you use `Vue` (like `Vue.set()`) inside the not listed 
`actions.js`, `mutations.js` or `getters.js`, but forgot to add:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

In the beginning of that file.

Comment: I have added the source of code of `actions.js`, `mutations.js` and `getters.js` in my original question. I don't use Vue.set in any of these files. Any other idea?

Comment: Oh, wow! I've just found the issue. I am doing `Vue.http()` but do not import Vue. Problem solved. Thank you. You helped me solve it.

Answer (score -1):

In GSP it's

```
<asset:javascript src="/vuebundle.js"/>
```